# Patterns for displaying errors

Tags: ruby

In my code, I usually employ the following setup:

```
module MyLib
  VERSION = "0.1.1"
  ERROR = [
    "You can either give one arg and a block or two args, not both.",
    "Yadda yadda..."
  ]
end
```

Then somewhere in my code:

```
def my_method(*args, &blk)
  raise(ArgumentError, MyLib::ERROR[0]) if (...condition snipped...)
end
```

Is there a better way to define error messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define your own exception classes:

```
module MyLib
  class FooError < ArgumentError
    def to_s
      "You can either give one arg and a block or two args, not both.",
    end
  end
end
```

Now if you raise it:

```
raise MyLib::FooError
MyLib::FooError: You can either give one arg and a block or two args, not both.
    from (irb):46
```

And if you want to handle it:

```
rescue MyLib::FooError
```